# Custom config file elements in ASP.NET: `Property is not a ConfigurationElement'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I'm attempting to implement my first go-around of reading custom configuration elements from an ASP.NET web.config file. It seems pretty simple to me, yet I'm receiving a run-time `Property is not a ConfigurationElement' error. Here's my code:

**The web.config file sections:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>...
<configuration>
  ...
  <section name="appConfig" type="ParticipationManagement.AppConfig" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowLocation="true" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  ...
  <appConfig>
    <startRecertVFC>2/15</startRecertVFC>
  </appConfig>
</configuration>
```

**The handler:**

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace ParticipationManagement
{
    public class AppConfig : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("startRecertVFC", IsRequired = false)]
        public DateTime RecertVFCStart
        {
            get
            {
                string start = (string)this["startRecertVFC"];
                string year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
                DateTime start_date;

                if (DateTime.TryParse(start + "/" + year, out start_date))
                {
                    return start_date;
                }
                else
                {
                    return DateTime.Today;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                this["startRecertVFC"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And my invocation in page code:**

```c#
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
...

            AppConfig config = (AppConfig)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appConfig");
            RecertVFCStart = config.RecertVFCStart;

        }
```

Seems very clean and straight-forward to me, but I'm getting that troubling error at runtime and I cannot narrow it down since I have no experience with this.

Sorry in advance: I see plenty of other posts about this but all seem to address more advanced/complex issues than what I'm trying to accomplish, which is nothing more than embedding a few app-specific values in an external file...

Answer (score -2):

1. Change your config setting like an example shown below

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
   <configSections>
    <section name="appConfig" type="ParticipationManagement.AppConfig" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowLocation="true" requirePermission="false"/>
   </configSections>        
   <appConfig startRecertVFC="5/1/2015 8:30:52 AM"  />
   </configuration>
   ```
2. Try to make the following change in  AppConfig file

   string start = this["startRecertVFC"].ToString();

Let us know if this solves your problem